# Java, Checking if any process ID is currently running on Windows

Tags: java, windows, pid

Is it possible to check the existence of process from Java in Windows.

I have its possible PID, I want to know if it is still running or not.

Comment: sure. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26423642/985297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this can help:

http://blogs.oracle.com/vaibhav/entry/listing_java_process_from_java

That post explains how to get all PIDs running on a Windows machine: you'd have to compare the output of the `cmd` call with your PID, instead of printing it.

If you're on Unix-like systems you'd have to use with `ps` instead of `cmd`

Calling system commands from your java code is not a very portable solution; then again, the implementation of processes varies among operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

### How to check if a pid is running on Windows with Java:

**Windows tasklist command:**

The DOS command `tasklist` shows some output on what processes are running:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eric>tasklist

Image Name                   PID Session Name     Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ====== ================ ======== ============
System Idle Process            0 Console                 0         28 K
System                         4 Console                 0        244 K
smss.exe                     856 Console                 0        436 K
csrss.exe                    908 Console                 0      6,556 K
winlogon.exe                 932 Console                 0      4,092 K
....
cmd.exe                     3012 Console                 0      2,860 K
tasklist.exe                5888 Console                 0      5,008 K

C:\Documents and Settings\eric>
```

**The second column is the PID**

You can use `tasklist` to get info on a specific PID:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 1300"
```

prints:

```
Image Name                   PID Session Name     Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ====== ================ ======== ============
mysqld.exe                  1300 Console                 0     17,456 K

C:\Documents and Settings\eric>
```

A response means the PID is running.

**If you query a PID that does not exist, you get this:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eric>tasklist /FI "PID eq 1301"
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.
C:\Documents and Settings\eric>
```

### A Java function could do the above automatically

This function will only work on Windows systems that have `tasklist` available.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class IsPidRunningTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //this function prints all running processes
        showAllProcessesRunningOnWindows();

        //this prints whether or not processID 1300 is running
        System.out.println("is PID 1300 running? " + 
            isProcessIdRunningOnWindows(1300));

    }

    /**
     * Queries {@code tasklist} if the process ID {@code pid} is running.
     * @param pid the PID to check
     * @return {@code true} if the PID is running, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isProcessIdRunningOnWindows(int pid){
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String cmds[] = {"cmd", "/c", "tasklist /FI \"PID eq " + pid + "\""};
            Process proc = runtime.exec(cmds);

            InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Search the PID matched lines single line for the sequence: " 1300 "
                //if you find it, then the PID is still running.
                if (line.contains(" " + pid + " ")){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Cannot query the tasklist for some reason.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Prints the output of {@code tasklist} including PIDs.
     */
    public static void showAllProcessesRunningOnWindows(){
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String cmds[] = {"cmd", "/c", "tasklist"};
            Process proc = runtime.exec(cmds);
            InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Cannot query the tasklist for some reason.");
        }
    }
}
```

The Java code above prints a list of all running processes then prints:

```
is PID 1300 running? true
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
boolean isStillAllive(String pidStr) {
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    String command = null;
    if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
        log.debug("Check alive Windows mode. Pid: [{}]", pidStr);
        command = "cmd /c tasklist /FI \"PID eq " + pidStr + "\"";
        return isProcessIdRunning(pidStr, command);
    } else if (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
        log.debug("Check alive Linux/Unix mode. Pid: [{}]", pidStr);
        command = "ps -p " + pidStr;
        return isProcessIdRunning(pidStr, command);
    }
    log.debug("Default Check alive for Pid: [{}] is false", pidStr);
    return false;
}


boolean isProcessIdRunning(String pid, String command) {
    log.debug("Command [{}]",command );
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);

        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        String strLine = null;
        while ((strLine= bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (strLine.contains(" " + pid + " ")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Got exception using system command [{}].", command, ex);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. import jna from Maven to your project
2. after maven was update you can use:

int myPid = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();