# Is it possible to create an instance of Process class if I have pid? Java

Tags: java, pid

Is it possible to create an instance of Process class if I have pid of process which already running? And put this Process in Map processMap. And then be able to stop Processes or check IsAlive

Comment: and do what with it? Are you simply looking to find if that process has completed, or are you trying to connect to its streams, or ...

Comment: @Andy and put this Process in Map<String, Process> processMap. And then be able to stop Processes or check IsAlive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) is for:

> Process provides control of native processes started by ProcessBuilder.start and Runtime.exec.

That's not to say you can't control already-running processes from Java; it's just that `Process` isn't the thing you should use to do it.

You can make your own class to do what you say you need, e.g:

```
interface ExternalProcess {
  boolean isRunning();

  void kill();
}
```

with implementations of the methods such as:

- [Verify if a process is running using its PID in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460775/verify-if-a-process-is-running-using-its-pid-in-java)
- [Killing a process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java)